# How to unit test cookie creation upon successful login in Vitest?

Tags: javascript, vitest

I'm trying to write a unit test in Vitest format for the following which covers cookie creation upon successful login.

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
  id: "auth",
  state: () => ({
    /* Initialize session state from cookie */
    session: useCookie("session"),
  }),
  actions: {
    async login(loginForm) {
      await useAPIFetch("/login", {
        method: "POST",
        body: loginForm,
      })
        .then((response) => {
          const responseData = response.data.value;
          const sessionCookie = useCookie("session", {
            maxAge: 86400, // 1 Day
            sameSite: true,
          });
          this.session = sessionCookie.value = responseData;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          throw error;
        });
    },
    logout() {
      const sessionCookie = useCookie("session");
      this.session = sessionCookie.value = null;
      navigateTo("/login");
    },
  },
});
```

This is what I currently have and I can't seem to get it to pass.

```
import { describe, test, expect, vi, beforeEach } from "vitest";
import { defineStore } from "./auth";
import { useAuthStore } from "./auth";

vi.mock("./auth.js", () => ({
  useCookie: vi.fn(),
}));

vi.mock("./auth.js", () => ({
  useAPIFetch: vi.fn(),
}));

vi.mock("./auth.js", () => ({
  navigateTo: vi.fn(),
}));

describe("useAuthStore", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {

    useAuthStore.$reset();
 
    useCookie.mockClear();
    useAPIFetch.mockClear();
    navigateTo.mockClear();
  });

  test("login action should update session state", async () => {
   
    const responseData = { token: "fakeToken" };

    useCookie.mockReturnValueOnce({
      value: null,
    });

   
    useAPIFetch.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      data: {
        value: responseData,
      },
    });

    await useAuthStore.login({ username: "user", password: "pass" });

    expect(useAuthStore.session).toEqual(responseData);

    expect(useCookie).toHaveBeenCalledWith("session", {
      maxAge: 86400,
      sameSite: true,
    });

    expect(useAPIFetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: { username: "user", password: "pass" },
    });
  });

  test("logout action should reset session state and navigate to login", () => {
   
    useAuthStore.session = { token: "fakeToken" };


    useAuthStore.logout();

    
    expect(useAuthStore.session).toBeNull();

    
    expect(navigateTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/login");
  });
});
```